# How to pixelar image in php

Tags: php, image

What I'm trying to do is to pixelate an image of a url, add another image above it and last save that image.

I have obtained this internet code to pixelate images but I think it does not work correctly. It does not show me the pixelated image nor does it save it. Just the black screen remains.

```
$pixel = 15;

$getImagen = 'https://ep00.epimg.net/elpais/imagenes/2017/06/05/album/1496652756_562670_1496654035_album_normal.jpg';


$imagen = imagecreatefromjpeg($getImagen); 
if(!$imagen) exit('ERROR');
list($ancho,$alto)=getimagesize($getImagen);
$superficieTotal = $ancho*$alto;    
//
$superficieRecorrida = 0;
$auxX=0;
$auxY=0;
while($superficieRecorrida <= $superficieTotal){
    $posX=0;$posY=0;$data = array();
    while($posX <= $pixel and (($auxX + $posX) < $ancho)){
        $posY=0;
        while($posY <= $pixel and (($auxY + $posY) < $alto)){
            $rgb = imagecolorat($imagen, ($auxX + $posX), ($auxY + $posY));
            $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
            $data[] = array($r,$g,$b);
            $posY++;
        }
        $posX++;
    }

    // Busco promedio
    $r = 0; $g = 0; $b = 0;
    foreach($data as $d){
        $r+= $d[0];
        $g+= $d[1];
        $b+= $d[2];
    }
    $totalArray = count($data);
    if($totalArray == 0) $totalArray = 1;
    $r = $r/$totalArray;
    $g = $g/$totalArray;
    $b = $b/$totalArray;
    $colorPromedio = imagecolorallocate($imagen, $r, $g, $b);
    imagefilledrectangle($imagen, $auxX, $auxY, ($auxX + $pixel), ($auxY + $pixel), $colorPromedio);
    //
    $auxX+= $pixel;
    if($auxX >= $ancho){
        $auxX = 0;
        $auxY+= ($pixel+1);
    }       
    $superficieRecorrida+= $pixel*$pixel;

}
//
Header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($imagen);
imagedestroy($imagen);
```

Thanks for your future answers. a greeting